# Zlib built with vcpkg - error while linking in MSVC 2015 in x86 mode

Tags: c++, linker, vcpkg

I have built zlib with vcpkg. I have tried several variants, like:

```
vcpkg install zlib
vcpkg install zlib:x86-windows-static
vcpkg install zlib:x64-windows-static
```

Now, I have a simple minizip demo and I want to use the static zlib (zlib.lib) that I built.

In x64 mode, all is linking correctly against x64 zlib. However, in x86 mode, I have these errors for the x86 zlib library:

```
1>mz_crypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crc32@12 referenced in function _mz_crypt_crc32_update
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate@8 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_deflate
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd@4 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_close
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflate@8 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_read
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateEnd@4 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_close
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateInit2_@32 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_open
1>mz_strm_zlib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateInit2_@16 referenced in function _mz_stream_zlib_open
```

I am using these preprocesor macros:

```
ZLIB_WINAPI
HAVE_ZLIB
MZ_ZIP_NO_ENCRYPTION
```

and code generation is set to: `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.

Comment: I feel you need to file a bug report for this port at the vcpkg github site.

Comment: How are you using the library with minizip? CMake, visual studio integration, nuget export?

Comment: Visual studio intergation - library directory and library in linker as an Additional dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, I have solved this by removing

```
ZLIB_WINAPI
```

for x86 build.